# eclipse complain compilation error for play 2.0.1

Tags: eclipse, playframework, playframework-2.0

The eclipse complain the following compilation error for play 2.0.1

```
     The type play.api.templates.Html cannot be resolved. It is 
indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

But in play console, it can successfully compile.

anything wrong with my environment ? has anyone encounter this issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the solution, I need to put target/scala-2.9.1/src_managed/main to source folder